# Spring AOP not being applied

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I trying to apply MethodBeforeAdvice but unable to do so. I am unable to figure out what is wrong with it. Please help me with it.

```
//Interface
package org.mycode;

public interface IHello {
   boolean authenticate(String input);
}


//Class on which advice need to be applied
package org.mycode;

public class HelloImpl implements IHello {

  @Override
  public boolean authenticate(String input) {
    System.out.println("authecated successfully");
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.out.println(input);
    return true;
  }

}


}


//Advice class
package org.mycode;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.springframework.aop.MethodBeforeAdvice;

public class MethodAdvice1 implements MethodBeforeAdvice {
  @Override
  public void before(Method arg0, Object[] arg1, Object arg2) throws  Throwable {
    System.out.println("checking for authentication of the caller");
    System.out.println(arg0.getName());
    System.out.println(arg0.getDeclaringClass().getName());
    System.out.println(arg1);
    System.out.println("time start: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
  }
}

//Client for the Adviced class
package org.mycode;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

public class AdviceManager {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathResource cp = new ClassPathResource("org/mycode/config.xml");
    BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(cp);
    HelloImpl hil = (HelloImpl) factory.getBean("myClass");

    System.out.println(hil.authenticate("AdvicedMethod"));
  }
}  


//Config file
config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="advice1" class="org.mycode.MethodAdvice1"></bean>
<bean id="myClass" class="org.mycode.HelloImpl"></bean>
<bean id="aspect1"
    class="org.springframework.aop.support.RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor">
    <property name="advice" ref="advice1"></property>
    <property name="pattern">
        <value>.*</value>
    </property>
 </bean>

<bean id="advicedHello" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="proxyInterfaces">
         <value>org.mycode.IHello</value>
    </property>
    <property name="target" ref="myClass" />
    <property name="interceptorNames">
         <list>
            <value>aspect1</value>
         </list>
    </property>
 </bean>
</beans>
```

output on running 
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/mycode/config.xml]
authecated successfully
1467340328875
AdvicedMethod
true

Comment: Instead of `myClass` get `advicedHello`. Don't use a `ProxyFactoryBean` anymore, use the `<aop:config />` if you really want to do it in xml. Using the (very) old style `ProxyFactoryBean` basically duplicates your bean definitions (one plain and one proxied instance). Although you could direct put the bean inside the proxy on the `target (instead of a `ref` put the `bean` element inside the tag).

Comment: Thanks you M.Deinum.